# multicolumns in latex

Tags: multicol

I try to have a one column setup and some parts with two column. But I don't want to make a `table` because it should not care about linebreaks is there a solution for that in `LaTeX`?

[image]

Comment: `multicol` provides `multicols` environment

Comment: or if you want a page break when switching between one and two column you can use `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` commands with no package needed.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thank you for your answer. How can I change the induvidual col width with that?

Comment: Check if some options from [this external link (discussion)](https://www.linkedin.com/groupAnswers?viewQuestionAndAnswers=&discussionID=5848790331536982018&gid=1600297&commentID=5858673535433605120&goback=%2Eamf_1600297_199688572&trk=NUS_DISC_Q-subject#commentID_5858673535433605120) may be helping.

Answer (score 1):

`longtable` actually did the trick. It breaks the table over several pages and is adjustable in linewidth.

Example is given below:

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,tbtags]{hepthesis}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
    ...
    \begin{longtable}{L{0.2\linewidth} L{0.8\linewidth}}
        A & bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd\\
        A & bcd \\
    \end{longtable}
    ...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this job, it is better to use a list for if you use `longtable`, it won't break within a row across the pages.

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,tbtags]{hepthesis}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{items}{description}{1}
\setlist[items]{align=parleft,font=\normalfont, leftmargin=0.2\textwidth,style=nextline,labelsep=0.5em,}

\begin{document}
    \begin{items}
        \item[A] bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd bcd
        \item[A] bcd \\
    \end{items}

\end{document}
```

[image]